# Angularjs $watch wont work on a model inside a directive but will work on a property of a model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code in a directives link function

```
link: function (element, attrs, linker) {
              return function ($scope, lElement, attrs){

                  $scope.$watch('hello.message', function () {
                         console.log($scope.hello.message);
                  });

                 //Id like to just watch he model this bit it wont work
                  $scope.$watch('hello', function () {
                         console.log($scope.hello.message);
                  });
              }
        }
```

can someone explain why watching just the model wont work? 
If I watch the model $.scope.hello the $watch inside the directive wont work
Do I need to include or set some other property in the directive options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting $watch third parameter ([objectEquality](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)) to true

Comment: Yup that definitely did the trick, thanks for pointing that out. I kept overlooking that third parameter.